# How do I bring a Java Input pop up to the foreground using C#

Tags: c#, windows, process

I'm a complete newbie, so please forgive my lack of terminology. I wanted to create a WPF/C# app that would grab a java application and input the information for me. So after searching on StackOverflow I saw an example on how to search for processes. So I modified it to search for javaw and bring it to the foreground. Which does work when the login screen comes up. But my issue is that before the login screen comes up there is an input pop up for choosing locations. That I can't seem to select and when I try to do p.GetPRocesses() and Console.WriteLine for each one. I don't see anything resembling the input pop up. How would I be able to select this input pop up? I know if I go to task manager I'm able to right click and choose "Bring to Front" and it works. So there has to be a way for me to find this process so I can manipulate it by bringing it to the foreground or move it around and etc. Also if it helps, I'm doing this on a windows 10 computer and there is only one java application running. I also wanted to say I tried searching for "input" as well for process name. Since that what was showing in Task Manager. But that didn't work.

```
    [System.Runtime.InteropServices.DllImport("user32")]
    private static extern bool SetForegroundWindow(IntPtr hwnd);
    var p = Process.GetProcessesByName("javaw").FirstOrDefault();
    SetForegroundWindow(p.MainWindowHandle);
```

[What shows in Task Manager](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gl819.png)

[Input Pop Up, That I'm trying to select](https://i.stack.imgur.com/l9QjX.png)

Comment: I think you might struggle a bit with this form of IPC because ISTR java doesn't necessarily use native window controls that you can find and poke values into with P/Invoke. You might have to resort to SendKeys. The input pop up would surely be the thing that comes to the front when Javaw is foregrounded, no? It's a modal dialog right? Is there any bother way you can better interact with this process or with what this process interacts with? What does the java program do? Why are you trying to use it programmatically?

Comment: Hello Caius Jard!
I'm going to be honest and say I don't know what P/Invoke and SendKeys is yet. But I will read up on it shortly. I was hoping to find out how to find the process first and slowly learn step by step on what I have to do next to input the values automatically. I did look up "Modal Dialog" Which sounds a lot like what the input pop up is. It generally is foreground when I load the java application and don't touch anything afterwards but sometimes it won't, if I'm clicking or typing on another application.

Comment: Well you're already using P/Invoke there with `SetForegroundWIndow` ;) - SendKeys simulates the keyboard.. I'm keen to knpow more about WHY you're doing this because it'll always be a really fragile way to get that java app to do its thing. There may be a more robust and easier to develop way of doing the same thing

Comment: Basically, the application we use at work is sort of funky.... When we start the application it creates pop up and ask for stuff like which customer location we want to log into and then our support staff credential to get in. But a lot of the time that pop up doesn't come in in the foreground and might be completely random on where it start up at. So the support staff (Me) have to minimize everything and try to find it. Which is just irritating/frustrating. The original developer have long abandon the tool and there is no plan to replace it or fix it. Even though we use it daily.

Comment: But after Caius Jard. Comment, I reached out to a bunch of people internally at my company and I was able to find out that there was a bat file that we can use to pass an argument to the application and it will login into that specific location. So I was able to run the bat file with the argument to completely bypass that modal dialog. Which is a lot easier than trying to figure out the way I was trying originally. Thanks Caius Jard!

Comment: In case anyone want's to know how to pass the argument for a bat file.

Process proc = new Process();
proc.StartInfo.WorkingDirectory = "path to file";
                    proc.StartInfo.FileName = "FileName.bat";
                    proc.StartInfo.Arguments = "Argument";
                    proc.Start();

Comment: Might also be worth pointing out that whatever the bat file does you can replicate into C# if you want to cut out another layer of the onion :)